# Passing a selected mysql_fetch_array() value to a processing script

Tags: php, mysql

This script takes all values from the users table and outputs them in a 'send friend request' type scenario for a social network I'm building. So how do I successfully pass $row['id'] to process-request.php?

```
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    if($userid != $row['user_pid']) {
    echo $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'];
    echo "<form method='POST' action='processing/process-request.php'>";
    echo '<input name="accepted" type="submit" value="Send User Request" /><br />';
    echo '<input name="AddedMessage" placeholder="Add a message?" type="textbox" />';
    echo '<br>Select Friend Type: ' . '<br />Full: ';
    echo '<input name="full_friend" type="checkbox"';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $row["id"] . '" />';
    echo '</form>';
    echo "<br /><hr />";
    } elseif ($userid == $row['user_pid']) {
    echo $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'];
    echo "<br />";
    echo "You all are already friends";
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question... Don't you already have a form for that?

Comment: You really should look up [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc)s for outputting chunks of html like that.

Comment: You should not use `SELECT * FROM users`. That's a suicide

Comment: What do you suggest I use then? I have allot of fields in the users table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already using sessions,

```
$_SESSION['row-id'] = $row['id'];
```

Comment: Yeah I thought about Sessions but if I'm outputting 1,000+ values, will each value have it's own Session id? or will just the value passed to the processing script have one?

Comment: @MichaelGrigsby Wait a sec, aren't you ALREADY passing $row['id'] to process-request.php in the hidden input element? You should be able to access it with $_POST['id'].

Comment: Likely because you've got invalid HTML. The 'full_friend' input tag isn't closed.